# How can I create this transparent embossed text effect in Adobe Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image]I saw this on social media and was wondering if someone could help me recreate it?

Answer (score 2):

It won't work with the emboss because it overshadow's (haha) the stroke. 
I think they used **two inner shadows** (one white on lighten, one black on multiply) for the relief effect, a regular **white stroke** and **drop shadow**. You'll have to play around abit with the adjustments. Also it seems like they upped the **saturation** of the text (see at the H) with an Adjustment Layer > Hue/Saturation (use the mask to select only the text)

Since the background picture is a bit too detailed it doesn't look the same. I'm also not sure if my method IS the same as used in your image but at least it comes close.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1, prepare background and text layer, use appropriate text font and size.
[image]

2, in layers panel, lower text layer's FILL to 0.

3, in layers panel, double click text layer's blank area(or right click->blending options), create some shadow.
[image]

4, now do some emboss effect:
[image]

5, now white edge:
[image]

6, All effects are done. Now fine tune all done effects in step 3~5 until satisfaction.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Create a new file and adjust the file size as per your requirement.
2. Now, create a new layer for background. Then, select the image tool for taking image or paint bucket tool for fill the background.
3. Select the background layer and add gradient with Layer > Layer Styles > Gradient Overlay and reduce the opacity 8%.
4. Now, add text through type tool and make it transparent.
5. Select the text layer and click “Layer” >Layer Style> Stroke. Similarly, add gradient and shadow in the text. Now it's done…